# How do I batch rename files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-rename

I have the following files in a common folder:

- recording01249
- recording01256
- recording01280
- recording01283
- recording01285

And want to have them renamed as follows:

- SP00001
- SP00002
- SP00003
- SP00004
- SP00005

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell. This will rename all files whose names begin with "recording" in current directory:

```
Get-ChildItem "recording*" | ForEach-Object -Begin { $count=1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("SP{0:D5}" -f $count++) }
```

You probably have files with extensions like ".wav", ".mp3" or something like that. If you wish to keep that extension, modify the `{0:D5}` part like so: `{0:D5}.wav`.

If you prefer more graphical solutions, you can use a free software for renaming files, like [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com).